# how to setup a sqoop2 application project in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, sqoop2

I'm referencing [Sqoop Client API Guide](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.2/ClientAPI.html). Inside the guide, it says:

> It requires Sqoop Client JAR and its dependencies.

It then lists the maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.sqoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>sqoop-client</artifactId>
  <version>${requestedVersion}</version>
</dependency>
```

Does that mean I need to setup a maven project with the dependency above? If not, where do I find and download the Sqoop Client JAR and its dependencies?

Thanks much!

Comment: yes create  a maven project with above dependency

Answer (score 0):

This is how I setup right now and it works for now but I highly doubt this is the "official recommended" way:

- Download all the required jar files from [this link](https://jar-download.com/?detail_search=g%25253A%252522org.apache.sqoop%252522%20AND%20a%25253A%252522sqoop-client%252522&search_type=3&a=sqoop-client). The link points to jar-download.com and claims to offer sqoop client JAR and dependencies for 1.99.6
- unzip the downloaded zip file from above
- create a java project in eclipse and "configure build path" then "Add External JARS ..." to include all the jars from downloaded zip file.

So far, I can import the sqoop java api class (i.e., `import org.apache.sqoop.client.SqoopClient;`) but I haven't tried to build the app.